# Dynamically allocating memory inside __device/global__ CUDA kernel

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, cuda, parallel-processing

According to the [CUDA Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2_prod/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) , Page 122, it is possible to dynamically allocate memory inside a **device/global** function so long as we're using compute architecture 2.x.

My problem is that when I attempt this I get the command line message:

> The command "some command" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" etc...

This is followed by an error saying that you cannot call a host function (malloc) from a *device/global* function.

The above message is showing that it is attempting to compile under compute 1.x. I am using VS2010 and have "Code Generation" set to "compute_20,sm_20" in the "CUDA C/C++" property page, so I am not sure why it is still trying to compile under compute 1.x. I am definitely using a card that supports 2.x. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to see the nvcc command line in the output.  In fact, I think that bit you pasted with all the -gencode/etc. in it *is* your command line.  Therefore, it is also proof that you are compiling the code for both sm_10 and sm_20, which is why you get the error when you call malloc.

You can confirm by wrapping the calls to malloc with `#if __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 200` and see if the error goes away.

I'm guessing that you set the properties to compile for sm_20 in the default properties for .cu files in your project, but *after* you added the .cu file to the project.  When the file was added to the project, the defaults were probably set to sm_10 and sm_20 (which is the default for the .rules file).  If you right-click on the file itself you might see that sm_20 is checked.  Just a hunch.

Comment: You were correct - I had set the default properties to compile under compute_20,sm_20. But when I checked the properties of the file itself it was still set to both compute_20,sm_20 and compute_10,sm_10. Altering this has now made my code compile successfully.