# Compiling for Compute Capability 2.x in CUDA C for VS2010

Tags: c, cuda, gpu

I was following this: [Dynamically allocating memory inside __device/global__ CUDA kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937693/dynamically-allocating-memory-inside-device-global-cuda-kernel)

But it still doesn't compile.

```
error : calling a host function("_malloc_dbg") from a __device__/__global__  
function("kernel") is not allowed

error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA  
\v4.1\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\"  
--use-local-env --cl-version 2010 -ccbin "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual  
Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64" -I"..\..\..\Source\Include" -G0  --keep-dir   
"x64\Debug" -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile  -g  -Xcompiler "/EHsc /nologo 
/Od /Zi  /MDd " -o "x64\Debug\move.cu.obj"  "C:\Source\scene\move.cu"" exited with  
code 2. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\CUDA  
4.1.targets     361 10
```

As suggested, I added `#if __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 200` and it returns false.

What else can be the issues? I'm running on a GTX480.

Edit: I have this warning as well: `#warning C4005: '_malloca' : macro redefinition`

Comment: Try compiling without debugging settings and see whether it makes any difference.

Comment: @talonmies, I continue to have the error. Could the warning (see Edit) be a source of concern?

Comment: There is a suspicious looking mixture of v4.0 and v4.1 in that error message. Are you sure you don't have more that one version of the CUDA toolkit installed? (Sorry I don't use VS so I can't really help with its internals).

Comment: Both errors were being caused by the macro redefinition, once I removed the header filed that caused the warning the program complied and runs perfectly.

`#if __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 200` still returns false. Not sure why, but doesn't matter now.

Yes, the mixture of 4.0 and 4.1 is very suspicious, but I definitely only have 4.1 installed. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you solved your main problem but there is the remaining question:

> I added `#if __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 200` and it returns false.

The CUDA code is compiled at least *twice*. In one compilation pass the CPU code is generated, in another pass, the device code. `__CUDA_ARCH__` is defined *only* for the device code generation.
It is possible to make even more compilation passes and produce GPU code for several architectures. The code for CPU would not change, but the GPU will.

I suspect that you are testing the `#if __CUDA_ARCH__ >= 200` when producing CPU code.